# Turn every second row into column

Tags: awk

I'm reformatting some ugly data that started as xml and all manner of other garbage and boiled down to this, but I can't quite finish the job.

I want to turn:

```
    BPSD-41 
    Admin Summary: Page does not finish loading

    BPSD-49 
    Mobile: Activity Section: Does not finish loading

    BPSD-50 
    Fix bug in staging
```

into this:

```
    BPSD-41 : Admin Summary: Page does not finish loading

    BPSD-49 : Mobile: Activity Section: Does not finish loading

    BPSD-50 : Fix bug in staging
```

I'll bet there's a really elegant awk solution, but I can't find it...

Comment: For a one-off, in vim you could do: `:%s/\([0-9]\) \n/\1 : /g`

Comment: You, sir, are a scholar and a gentleman.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
BEGIN {
    flag = 0;
}

{
    if (flag == 0) {
        save = $0;
        flag = 1;
    } else {
        printf("%s : %s\n", save, $0);
        flag = 0;
    }
}
```

Note that I haven't tested this, but something close should work.

Comment: `BPSD-2  : Copy change for Local Spending pod on summary page
 :   BPSD-7 
Error Creating Transactions in Admin Portal : 
  BPSD-3  : test Home Page: Change contact phone number
 :   BPSD-4 `

Comment: Alex, I don't understand the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk command to join 2 lines:

```
awk 'NF>0{printf $0; getline; print $0}' inFile
```

OR use sed:

```
sed -i.bak 'N;s/\n/\;/' inFIle
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner that skips blank lines

```
/[^\r\n]/{ printf("%s%s", $0, i++ % 2 ? "\n" : " : "); }
```